# Which version of SharePoint Designer 2013 should I take

Tags: sharepoint-designer

All, There are two versions of `SharePoint Designer 2013`-32bit and 64bit. If my OS is `Windows 7 64Bit`. Which one should I take ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend 64bit as it is future. Please read the below Technet blogs, in that blog author talking about 32 bit vs 64bit version of Office products(SharePoint designer is part of Office.)

[Understanding 64-Bit Office](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2010/02/23/understanding-64-bit-office.aspx)

Comment: Good post , If I don't have the requirement to open large document and the previous version of Office is 32bit. So It doesn't need to think about the compatibility issue if I choose 32bit .Right ?

Comment: There's no compatibility issues with both version though your windows is 64 bit. The only thing to consider is, once you choose 32/64 bit version, later if you want to install Microsoft Office pack, should be the same version with SharePoint Designer.